# How to prevent a plot from the past repainting?

Tags: plot, pine-script, repaint

Is there a way to prevent a plot that has already appeared from erasing itself shortly after? I'm using pinescript on TradingView and an indicator sometimes does this. I'm aware it is due to security() and lookahead_on, and that repainting in the code should be avoided entirely, but I'd like to experiment with just making sure the plot itself is permanent when it appears, irrespective as to whether the code tells it to erase itself.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code.

For `security()` you can use the following function:

```
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

For other cases, you can use the `barstate.isconfirmed` built-in variable together with your other conditions that feeds the `plot()`. `barstate.isconfirmed` will be `true` with the last update of the bar. So, in that caase, the price action would be confirmed.